# Why can't certain dates be cast to timestamp format in Snowflake SQL?

Tags: sql, date, casting, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

## Source data has different formats

I am working with a nested JSON table and the `created_at` field cannot be cast to a timestamp.

Here is in essence what should work:

```
SELECT    
    TO_TIMESTAMP(json_data:created_at::VARCHAR, 'mm/dd/yyyy HH:MI:SS AM TZH:TZM') AS custom_date_cast
    , TO_TIMESTAMP(json_data:created_at::VARCHAR) AS default_date_cast
FROM my_table
```

> Reason why there is the two fields is because we have dates coming in with this format: `11/21/2022 12:25:30 PM +00:00` (custom_date_cast) and this format `2023-02-07T15:50:09.8385748+00:00` (default_date_cast).

In theory I would create a `CASE WHEN` to catch the two different cases, alias it to `created_at` and be done with it. However there are some dates that apparently fit neither of these casts.

## What I tried

Here's such an example I retrieved using this query:

```
SELECT    
    TRY_TO_TIMESTAMP(json_data:created_at::VARCHAR, 'mm/dd/yyyy HH:MI:SS AM TZH:TZM') AS custom_date_cast
    , TRY_TO_TIMESTAMP(json_data:created_at::VARCHAR) AS default_date_cast
    , json_data:created_at::VARCHAR AS created_at
FROM my_table
WHERE 
    TRY_TO_TIMESTAMP(json_data:created_at::VARCHAR, 'mm/dd/yyyy HH:MI:SS AM TZH:TZM') IS NULL 
    AND TRY_TO_TIMESTAMP(json_data:created_at::VARCHAR) IS NULL
```

Here's one such result: `4/8/2022 12:49:44 PM +00:00`. As you will notice, it is identical to one such example that does work such as: `1/22/2022 4:01:52 PM +00:00`.

If I use `TO_TIMESTAMP()` instead, I get this error for some entries (full breakdown below):

```
SQL Error [100096] [22007]: Can't parse '4/8/2022 12:49:44 PM +00:00' as timestamp with format 'mm/dd/yyyy HH:MI:SS AM TZH:TZM'
```

Using this query above I used a `COUNT(*)` to see how many cases we had with this weird anomaly. The results:

| AND | **Custom Casting Worked** | **Custom Casting Failed** |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **Default Casting Worked** | 0 | 957 |
| **Default Casting Failed** | 204,588 | 19,527 |

This means there are 19,527 entries that cannot be cast either by my custom cast or by the default casting method.

What is even stranger to me is that if I literally copy one of the "non-working" date as an example, then run this SELECT statement it will work just fine:

```
SELECT
    TO_TIMESTAMP('4/8/2022 12:49:44 PM +00:00', 'mm/dd/yyyy HH:MI:SS AM TZH:TZM');
```

Does anyone have any idea of what could be the problem or what I could try next?

Comment: There might be a scenario that , data might have some hidden junk characters some times.

Comment: Indeed I thought the same. So I split each character from the date to see if it would pick it up using `SUBSTR()` and could not find anything... Perhaps it still is but it's a character that isn't picked up by `SUBSTR`? Is there even such a thing?

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a Python UDF to parse the dates.

Anaconda already provides in Snowflake "dateutil":

- https://github.com/dateutil/dateutil/

It offers what you need:

> Generic parsing of dates in almost any string format;

For example:

```py
from dateutil.parser import *
now = parse("Sat Oct 11 17:13:46 UTC 2003")
```

Docs:

- https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html#dateutil.parser.parse